Closed form for expected CRRA utility under a GBM
I was wondering if my proof for deriving a closed form solution for the expected CRRA utility of the 10-year distribution of a GBM could be checked. The proof goes as follows (I'll assume prior knowledge of both CRRA and GBMs):
Given a GBM with growth $\mu$ and volatility $\sigma = \frac{\mu-r_f}{Sh}$, where $r_f$ is the risk-free rate and $Sh$ is a given Sharpe ratio. Furthermore, we have a CRRA utility maximising agent with risk aversion $\gamma$. Throughout we assume $\gamma \neq 1$. The claim is that the desired expected utility is given by:
$$\frac{1}{1-\gamma}\exp\bigg(10(1-\gamma)\bigg(\mu-r_f-\frac{\gamma}{2}\bigg(\frac{\mu-r_f}{Sh}\bigg)^2\bigg)\bigg).$$
For simplicity I'm going to write $\mu-r_f$ as just $\mu$ and substitute it in later.
Firstly, the GBM $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ defined by (with BM $W_t$)
$$ dX_t = \mu X_tdt+\sigma X_tdW_t$$
has the solution
$$X_t = \exp\bigg(\bigg(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\bigg)t+\sigma W_t\bigg).$$
Taking t to be years, we're interested in the value
$E\bigg[\frac{X_{10}^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}\bigg]$. Using the above, we can rewrite this as:
$$
\begin{equation}
E\bigg[\frac{X_{10}^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}\bigg] = \frac{1}{1-\gamma}E\bigg[\exp\bigg(10\bigg(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\bigg)+\sigma W_{10}\bigg)^{1-\gamma}\bigg] \\
= \frac{1}{1-\gamma}\exp\bigg(10(1-\gamma)\bigg(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\bigg)\bigg)E[\exp((1-\gamma)\sigma W_{10})].
\end{equation}
$$
Using the MGF of a Normal rv ($E[e^{aW_t}] = e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2t}$) this becomes
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{1-\gamma}\exp\bigg(10(1-\gamma)\bigg(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\bigg)+10\frac{(1-\gamma)^2\sigma^2}{2}\bigg)\\
= \frac{1}{1-\gamma}\exp\bigg(10(1-\gamma)\bigg(\mu-\frac{\gamma}{2}\sigma^2\bigg)\bigg).
\end{equation}
$$
Finally, making our subsitutions $\mu = \mu-r_f$ and $\sigma = \frac{\mu-r_f}{Sh}$ we obtain:
$$
E\bigg[\frac{X_{10}^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}\bigg] = \frac{1}{1-\gamma}\exp\bigg(10(1-\gamma)\bigg(\mu-r_f-\frac{\gamma}{2}\bigg(\frac{\mu-r_f}{Sh}\bigg)^2\bigg)\bigg).
$$
I would have expected this to be a fairly available proof so I was surprised when I couldn't find it. Are there any references detailing this? (I am somewhat limited by access so any guidance would be great).

For anyone wondering, you can use the results from this paper (e.g. Eq 1): http://webdoc.sub.gwdg.de/ebook/serien/e/monash_univ/wp1-09.pdf , with $\mu_r = (\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t$ and $\sigma_r^2 = \sigma^2t$.
